# SSE4 _mm_cmpistrm finding characters in a string (Full-code example)

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, assembly, sse

I am trying to return a _m128i bit mask from `_mm_cmpistrm`, which indicates which bytes in a 128 bit source contain a space. However, I am having a few problems because when I set the 1st and 3rd bytes to be spaces the results I get say {255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0....}  rather than {255,0,255,0,0,0,...}....

Could someone help/enlighten?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <nmmintrin.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    __m128i a, b;

    const int mode = _SIDD_UBYTE_OPS | _SIDD_CMP_EQUAL_ANY  | _SIDD_LEAST_SIGNIFICANT;

    a.m128i_u8[15] = 't';   
    a.m128i_u8[14] = 'e';
    a.m128i_u8[13] = 's';
    a.m128i_u8[12] = 'o';
    a.m128i_u8[11] = 'd';
    a.m128i_u8[10] = 'i';
    a.m128i_u8[9] = 'f';
    a.m128i_u8[8] = 'g';
    a.m128i_u8[7] = 't';
    a.m128i_u8[6] = 'd';
    a.m128i_u8[5] = 'b';
    a.m128i_u8[4] = 'n';
    a.m128i_u8[3] = 'd';
    a.m128i_u8[2] = ' ';
    a.m128i_u8[1] = 'i';
    a.m128i_u8[0] = ' ';

    b.m128i_u8[15] = ' ';
    b.m128i_u8[14] = ' ';
    b.m128i_u8[13] = ' ';
    b.m128i_u8[12] = ' ';
    b.m128i_u8[11] = ' ';
    b.m128i_u8[10] = ' ';
    b.m128i_u8[9] = ' ';
    b.m128i_u8[8] = ' ';
    b.m128i_u8[7] = ' ';
    b.m128i_u8[6] = ' ';
    b.m128i_u8[5] = ' ';
    b.m128i_u8[4] = ' ';
    b.m128i_u8[3] = ' ';
    b.m128i_u8[2] = ' ';
    b.m128i_u8[1] = ' ';
    b.m128i_u8[0] = ' ';

    __m128i returnValue = _mm_cmpistrm(a, b, mode);

    std::cout << int(static_cast<unsigned char>(returnValue.m128i_u8[0])) << endl;
    std::cout << int(static_cast<unsigned char>(returnValue.m128i_u8[1])) << endl;
    std::cout << int(static_cast<unsigned char>(returnValue.m128i_u8[2])) << endl;
    std::cout << int(static_cast<unsigned char>(returnValue.m128i_u8[3])) << endl;
    std::cout << int(static_cast<unsigned char>(returnValue.m128i_u8[4])) << endl;
    std::cout << int(static_cast<unsigned char>(returnValue.m128i_u8[5])) << endl;
    std::cout << int(static_cast<unsigned char>(returnValue.m128i_u8[6])) << endl;
    std::cout << int(static_cast<unsigned char>(returnValue.m128i_u8[7])) << endl;
    std::cout << int(static_cast<unsigned char>(returnValue.m128i_u8[8])) << endl;
    std::cout << int(static_cast<unsigned char>(returnValue.m128i_u8[9])) << endl;
    std::cout << int(static_cast<unsigned char>(returnValue.m128i_u8[10])) << endl;
    std::cout << int(static_cast<unsigned char>(returnValue.m128i_u8[11])) << endl;
    std::cout << int(static_cast<unsigned char>(returnValue.m128i_u8[12])) << endl;
    std::cout << int(static_cast<unsigned char>(returnValue.m128i_u8[13])) << endl;
    std::cout << int(static_cast<unsigned char>(returnValue.m128i_u8[14])) << endl;
    std::cout << int(static_cast<unsigned char>(returnValue.m128i_u8[15])) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two possible problems:

- I believe the result is a packed 16 bit field in the low order two bytes of the result vector, so your result in this case is 16 TRUE flags.
- you are using `_SIDD_CMP_EQUAL_ANY` and I think you probably need to be using `_SIDD_CMP_EQUAL_EACH` - if you make this change I think your result will then be 5, 0, 0, 0, ... indicating a match at elements 0 and 2.

Note: although I do a lot of work with SSE and AVX I've never used these string instructions so I'm just basing the above opinion on a quick perusal of the Intel docs.